# Monitor process exceptions via Debug API

Tags: debugging, exception

Any help to start using sample code find at [C++/CLI Win32 debugger library for x86](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/463167-c-dll-with-a-c-consumer/page__view__findpost__p__4052693) to monitor process exceptions.

Some code I made is :

```
using System;
using DebugLibrary;

namespace DebugTeste01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DebugUtil.DebugActiveProcess(4932);
            DebugEvent de = new DebugEvent();
            ThreadContext tc = new ThreadContext();
            LDTEntry ldte = new LDTEntry();

            do
            {
                debug_evt = DebugUtil.WaitForDebugEvent(0xffffffff);

                de = (DebugEvent)debug_evt;
                Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(de.processId);

                object meminfo = DebugUtil.GetMemoryInfo(proc.Handle);
                //...
                object modinf = DebugUtil.GetModuleInfo(proc.Handle);
                //...

                switch (debug_evt.GetType().ToString())
                {
                    case "DebugLibrary.DebugEvent_CreateProcess":
                        {
                            DebugEvent_CreateProcess decp = (DebugEvent_CreateProcess)debug_evt;
                            //some action, logging, etc.
                        }
                        break;
                    case "DebugLibrary.DebugEvent_LoadDll":
                        {
                            DebugEvent_LoadDll dect = (DebugEvent_LoadDll)debug_evt;
                            //some action, logging, etc.
                        }
                        break;
                    case "DebugLibrary.DebugEvent_CreateThread":
                        {
                            DebugEvent_CreateThread dect = (DebugEvent_CreateThread)debug_evt;
                            //some action, logging, etc.
                        }
                        break;
                    case "DebugLibrary.DebugEvent_ExitThread":
                        {
                            DebugEvent_ExitThread dect = (DebugEvent_ExitThread)debug_evt;
                            //some action, logging, etc.
                        }
                        break;
                    case "DebugLibrary.DebugEvent_Exception":
                        {
                            DebugEvent_Exception dect = (DebugEvent_Exception)debug_evt;

                            ExceptionRecord exbp = dect.exceptionRecord;

                            switch (exbp.GetType().ToString())
                            {
                                case "Breakpoint":
                                    {
                                        //some action, logging, etc.
                                        exbp = null;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "AccessViolation":
                                    {
                                        //some action, logging, etc.
                                        exbp = null;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                //more case
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            //some action, logging, etc.
                            debug_evt = null;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                try
                {
                    DebugUtil.ContinueDebugEvent(de.processId, de.threadId, false);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while ( true );
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] 03/14/2012
Good article: [Using the Windows Debugging API](http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/articles/SimpleDebugger.html)
[EDIT] 03/14/2012
Improvements in implementation.
Now it has an initial skeleton construction for a final application.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are after resources on debugger writing for understanding, in which case, your best place to start is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this gives the basics of what should be handled how. from there its really up to your application and environment how you handle the exceptions.

As a comment on your actual code, avoid hardcoding to a PID, rather use the process name.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to show how to use the API, but first have to understand how it works.